# Is every sheaf a subsheaf of a flasque sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, several-complex-variables

Call a sheaf **flasque** if for all open sets $U \subset V$, the restriction map$$\mathcal{F}(V) \to \mathcal{F}(U)$$is surjective. Is every sheaf a subsheaf of a flasque sheaf?

Comment: Yes, do you know what the étalé space of a sheaf is?

Comment: The search phrase here is "Godement resolution".

Comment: or 'sheaf of discontinuous sections.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let$$\mathcal{G} = \prod_{p \in X} \mathcal{F}_p.$$Then $\mathcal{F}$ is a subsheaf of $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ is easily seen to be flasque.

Comment: It may be a simple question, but how can you prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is a subsheaf of $\mathcal{G}$? I'm new to sheaf theory and I need to prove that there exists a sheaf monomorphism from any sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ to a flasque sheaf, which I expect to be this $\mathcal{G}$. If so, I guess it is equivalent to your statement. I could open a new question but it has to risk to be quite similar to this one, so... Thanks for your help :)